# jQuery irritating flicker issue - all browsers

Tags: jquery, animation

I have this piece of code that's being used to fade in other elements.

The problem I'm having is that it's causing the screen to flicker and sometimes the parent div to move up and down quickly upon change.

```
<script>
    $j=jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function() {

        var speed = 800,
        holdTime = 5000,
        num = 1,
        timer;

        (function rotate() {
            $j("#box-set-" + num).stop(true, true)
                                 .fadeIn(speed)
                                 .delay(holdTime)
                                 .fadeOut(speed);
            num >= 3 ? num=1 : num++;
            timer = setTimeout(rotate, holdTime + 1600);
        })();

    });
</script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDITED: Attached css

```
.box-hidden {
display:none;
margin: 0;
}

#box-sets {
height:225px;

}

#tag-box-1 {
width: 31.25%;
color: #999;
text-align: center;
line-height: 1.4em;
float: left;
margin-right: 3.125%;
margin-top: 0;
}
#tag-box-2 {
width: 31.25%;
color: #999;
text-align: center;
line-height: 1.4em;
margin-right: 3.125%;
float: left;
padding-top: 10px;
margin-top: 0;
}
#tag-box-3 {
width: 31.25%;
color: #999;
text-align: center;
line-height: 1.4em;
float: left;
padding-top: 10px;
margin-top: 0;
}
#home-page-spacer {
border-top: 6px solid #ededed;
border-bottom: 3px solid #ededed;
background-color: #fdfafa;
padding: 1em 0;
margin: 2em 0;
}
```

Comment: This may be down to CSS - can you show us the css fir `#box-set-*` and any relating parent elements

Comment: i'd imagine it's probably an overflow or positioning issue, however the way you're fadeIn & FadeOut is confusing, make a jsfiddle of it with the html

Comment: Here is the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/StW9t/

Comment: any help at all on this guys??